# Does a 2004 Chevy Malibu have a cabin air filter

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, cabin-filter

A couple of questions.

1. Does a 2004 Chevy Malibu have a cabin air filter?
2. If so, where would it be located?
3. How often should a cabin air filter be changed?

Comment: http://www.carcarekiosk.com/video/2006_Chevrolet_Malibu_LS_2.2L_4_Cyl./air_filter_cabin/replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Maybe.
2. If you get the glove box out out the way, if you
   have one it will probably be accessible through the space it usually
   occupies.  Don't break the glove box, you'll need to disengage
   whatever mechanism is holding it in the open position when you
   release the latch.
3. According to the manufacturer service
   schedule or whenever it's filthy / clogged.

Some quick searching is turning up a lot of confusing info.  You may have one that came with the vehicle from the factory, but it might not be in any parts database as a part you can order / purchase.  You might also just have an empty spot where you could fit a filter.  Here's a [thread](http://www.chevymalibuforum.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-10021.html) from [chevymalibuforum.com.](http://www.chevymalibuforum.com).